# Configure authentication dynamically

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, async-await, api-gateway, ocelot

[Context]

I'm testing an identity provider. And I came across an intriguing scenario where ... the introspect endpoint was still missing which means, i'm going to validate the token by myself like so:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json");

        var response = await client.GetAsync("url_to_jwks");
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();            
        var jwk = new JsonWebKeySet(content).GetSigningKeys().First();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer("SelfValidationKey", opt =>
            {
                opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = jwk
                };
                opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });
        services.AddOcelot();
```

There are others parameters to check of course, but just for simplicity, we'll just focus on the signature, and because that's also my problem :)

[The idea]

Instead of verifying it with a certificate, why not use the jwk provided by the IdP well-known document (the jwk is not always the same). And that's what I did, and it works, but! When I try to make an http call inside my configure services, before adding authentification, it crashes:

*System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Ocelot.Middleware.OcelotMiddlewareExtensions.CreateConfiguration(IApplicationBuilder builder)
at Ocelot.Middleware.OcelotMiddlewareExtensions.UseOcelot(IApplicationBuilder builder, OcelotPipelineConfiguration pipelineConfiguration)
at Ocelot.Middleware.OcelotMiddlewareExtensions.UseOcelot(IApplicationBuilder builder)
at ApiGateway.Startup.Configure*

I thought I couldn't make http calls inside my service configuration, but acutally I checked and I do receive the response I was expecting. I've tried it on a different startup.cs and it works just fine, so my guess ... it has to do with Ocelot (api gateway) somehow, am I making the async/await statement in the wrong way? The exception is thrown at Programs .cs which is very basic, and I never reach *Services.AddAuthentication()*:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

            builder.ConfigureServices(s => s.AddSingleton(builder))
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(
                    ic => ic.AddJsonFile("ocelot.json"))
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            var host = builder.Build();
            return host;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way was to ...

Make a call through my static class *IdpDocument* in my program.cs, pass the value I need to the configuration via UseSetting method, which is then injected into the startup.cs, and it looks like this:

```cs
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        jwks = await IdpDocument.FetchJwks();
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

        builder.ConfigureServices(s => s.AddSingleton(builder))
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(
                ic => ic.AddJsonFile("ocelot.json"))
            .UseSetting("jwks", jwks)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
        var host = builder.Build();
        return host;
    }
```

And in my startup.cs, i get the value:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     var jwks = Configuration.GetValue<string>("jwks");
     // and the rest of the code ...
}
```

But ... my only concern with that is .. I only make the request once. So, what if the jwks get updated? (which is not this program responsibility)

The only way to get the right keys, is to re-run this program which .. is not really clean.